# kubernetes - Couldn't able to join master node - error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server

Tags: kubernetes

I am novice to k8s, so this might be very simple issue for someone with expertise in the k8s.

I am working with two nodes

1. master - 2cpu, 2 GB memory
2. worker - 1 cpu, 1 GB memory
3. OS - ubuntu - hashicorp/bionic64

I did setup the master node successfully and i can see it is up and running

```
vagrant@master:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master   Ready    master   29m   v1.18.2
```

Here is token which i have generated

```
vagrant@master:~$ kubeadm token create --print-join-command
W0419 13:45:52.513532   16403 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
kubeadm join 10.0.2.15:6443 --token xuz63z.todnwgijqb3z1vhz     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:d4dadda6fa90c94eca1c8dcd3a441af24bb0727ffc45c0c27161ee8f7e883521
```

**Issue** - But when i try to join it from the worker node i get

```
vagrant@worker:~$ sudo kubeadm join 10.0.2.15:6443 --token xuz63z.todnwgijqb3z1vhz     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:d4dadda6fa90c94eca1c8dcd3a441af24bb0727ffc45c0c27161ee8f7e883521 
W0419 13:46:17.651819   15987 join.go:346] [preflight] WARNING: JoinControlPane.controlPlane settings will be ignored when control-plane flag is not set.
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: Get https://10.0.2.15:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s: dial tcp 10.0.2.15:6443: connect: connection refused
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Here are the ports which are occupied

```
10.0.2.15:2379 
10.0.2.15:2380 
10.0.2.15:68
```

Note i am using CNI from -

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Comment: telnet 10.0.2.15 6443 or nc -v 10.0.2.15 6443 from the worker node and in master node check if port 6443 is listening or not.

Comment: It giving connection refused - vagrant@worker:~$ nc -v 10.0.2.15 6443
nc: connect to 10.0.2.15 port 6443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Comment: check what ports are  listening on master node bt running sudo netstat -tulpn on master

Comment: i can see following port - 
10.0.2.15:2379

10.0.2.15:2380

10.0.2.15:68

Comment: Could you share more information about your env? Those VMs are in Virtual box, Cloud, local network? Does Master and Worker have the same versions of Kubeadm, kubectl, docker? Any firewalls?

Comment: Yes both the VMs are in virtual box. Master and worker both have the same version i.e. - kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2", GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:54:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} . Firewalls are also disabled - vagrant@master:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this behaviour. Could you please provide all steps? What Minikube, docker version are you using? All versions are the same on each VM? Do you have any specific VirtualBox settings?

Answer (score 4):

1. Run the command 'kubectl config view' or 'kubectl cluster-info' to check the IP address of Kubernetes control plane. In my case it is 10.0.0.2.

   $  kubectl config view

   apiVersion: v1

   clusters:

   - cluster:

     certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED

     server: https://10.0.0.2:6443

   Or

   $  kubectl cluster-info

   Kubernetes control plane is running at https://10.0.0.2:6443
2. Tried to telnet the Kubernetes control plane.

   telnet 10.0.0.2 6443

   Trying 10.0.0.2...
3. Press Control + C in your keyboard to terminate the telnet command.
4. Go to your Firewall Rules and add port 6443 and make sure to allow all instances in the network.
5. Then try to telnet the Kubernetes control plane once again and you should be able to connect now:

   $ telnet 10.0.0.2 6443

   Trying 10.0.0.2...

   Connected to 10.0.0.2.

   Escape character is '^]'.
6. Try to join the worker nodes now. You can run the command 'kubeadm token create --print-join-command' to create new token just in case you forgot to save the old one.
7. Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the control-plane to see this node join the cluster

   $  kubectl get nodes

   NAME          STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION

   k8s           Ready    control-plane   57m   v1.25.0

   wk8s-node-0   Ready              36m   v1.25.0

   wk8s-node-1   Ready              35m   v1.25.0

Comment: Point 4 helped me to solve the connectivity issue.!! Specifically, I ran this command `ufw allow 6443` in master node and then the worker node could join the master node via `kubeadm join ...` command
Thanks!

Comment: @Shamim, I'm glad to hear that you're feeling positive about solving the connectivity issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here are mistakes which realized i did during my kubernetes installation -

(For detailed installation step follow - [Steps for Installation](http://jhooq.com/14-steps-to-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04/) )

But here are the key mistakes which i did -

***Mistake 1 -*** Since i was working on the VMs so i had multiple ethernet adapter on my both the VMs (master as well as worker ). By default the the CNI always takes the ***eth0*** but i our case it should be ***eth1***

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:bb:14:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:fb:48:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.0.0.1
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
```

***Mistake 2-*** The way i was initializing the my ***kubeadm*** without ***--apiserver-advertise-address*** and ***--pod-network-cidr***

So here is kubeadm command which i used -

```
[vagrant@master ~]$ sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=100.0.0.1 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

***Mistake 3 -*** - Since we have mulitple ethernet adapter in our VMs so i coudln't find the a way to set up extra args to switch from ***eth0*** to ***eth1*** in ***calico.yml*** configuration.

So i used **flannel CNI***

```
[vagrant@master ~]$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

and in the args section added  - ***--iface=eth1***

```
- --iface=eth1
        args:
        - --ip-masq
        - --kube-subnet-mgr
        - --iface=eth1
```

And it worked after that

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me using this **--apiserver-advertise-address**:

`sudo kubeadm init  --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.28.10 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`

`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml`

I have used calico and worked for me.

In Member node for join:

`kubeadm join 172.16.28.10:6443 --token 2jm9hd.o2gulx4x1b8l1t5d \ --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:b8b679e86c4d228bfa486086f18dcac4760e5871e8dd023ec166acfd93781595`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem while setting up the Kubernetes Master and worker node setup. I got the same error while adding the worker nodes to the master node. I just stopped the Firewalld and then tried adding the nodes adn then IT WORKED. Hope this helps someone.

Thanks

Comment: From Security perspective - It is recommended not to stop Firewalld. Try opening up specific ports if needed.

Answer (score 2):

When joining master node with slave nodes, received below error:

```
====================================================================
TASK [Joining worker nodes with kubernetes master] ***********************************************
fatal: [ip-0-0-0-0.ec2.internal]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "grep -i -A2 'kubeadm join' join_token|bash", "delta": "0:05:07.728008", "end": "2022-01-15 11:41:28.615600", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-01-15 11:36:20.887592", "stderr": "error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: Get \"https://139.41.82.79:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)\nTo see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher", "stderr_lines": ["error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: Get \"https://139.41.82.79:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)", "To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher"], "stdout": "[preflight] Running pre-flight checks", "stdout_lines": ["[preflight] Running pre-flight checks"]}

===============================================================================
```

If you observe the error carefully, you will see the ip address and port number as below:
`https://139.41.82.79:6443`

Solution:

Please follow the below steps to resolve:

1. Go to your security groups
2. Add the port number `6443` entry in your security group for custom IP, for `0.0.0.0:0`, and save the details.
3. Rerun the yaml script to join the master nodes with slave.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem and simply allowing port 6443 through firewall made it work and worker node successfully joined.

```
ufw allow 6443/tcp
ufw allow 6443/udp
```

Comment: I also made my worker node able to join by this way. I didn't mention the tcp or udp. Just ran `ufw allow 6443`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue, problem was my node VM's timezone was different. Corrected the time on node and it worked!

Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix: Expose `port:6443` in Security Group of my AWS EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

If the master is on Ubuntu 21.04 64 bit version ( VM) then opening up the firewall for the port used for joining the cluster using the command `sudo ufw allow 6443` will help

Answer (score 0):

With addition to the good examples gave for this issue by @Rahul Wagh - I'll just add the fact that I got this error because I ran `export KUBECONFIG` on the wrong `kubeconfig` file which was configured with an api-server endpoint which wasn't reachable.

Comment: You mean the .kube/config file?

Comment: Yes. thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Check if you could connect from Worker Node to Master with telnet

   telnet Master_IP 6443
2. If you could then please In Master Run kubeadm with **--apiserver-advertise-address=Master_IP** and **--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16**

**N.B:** 10.244.0.0/16 is Network CIDR for vagrant most of the time and save the join command

3. Then Create the pod network using CNI {***flannel/Calico/WeaveNet***}
4. Now run the join command which you saved from Worker Node {Here 10.0.2.15 will be set max time}

   kubeadm join 10.0.2.15:6443 --token 7gm48u.6ffny379c1mw3hpu 
   --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:936daab57e3302ed7b70f665af3d041736e265d19a16abc710fa0efbf318b5bf

Answer (score 0):

Well all I did was got to the was console and opened a port for master node. That simple. It worked immediately!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error I used an old config from a previous kubernetes installation or setup.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The below commands will remove the old config and copy the new config to the `.kube` directory as well as set the correct permissions:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.kube || true    
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube   
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config   
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Next, setup the networking and network policy:

```
CALICO_VERSION=3.27.2
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v${CALICO_VERSION}/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v${CALICO_VERSION}/manifests/custom-resources.yaml
```

Next, run the command below to get the generated token:

```
kubeadm token list
```

Next, join the worker node(s) to the cluster. Replace the place holders with the actual values:

```
kubeadm join <master node IP address>:6443 --token <generated token> \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash <kube config public keys>
```